Kafka AdminClient connection issue: "Connection with localhost/127.0.0.1 disconnected" in Spring application
I'm encountering an issue while connecting to my Kafka cluster from a Spring application running locally. The application successfully resolves localhost to 127.0.0.1 but then disconnects immediately, and no further communication occurs. Below are the relevant logs and my setup details.
Logs
INFO  [AdminClient clientId=authentication-service-admin-0] Completed connection to node -1. Fetching API versions.
DEBUG [AdminClient clientId=authentication-service-admin-0] Initiating API versions fetch from node -1.
DEBUG [AdminClient clientId=authentication-service-admin-0] Sending API_VERSIONS request with header ...
DEBUG [AdminClient clientId=authentication-service-admin-0] Connection with localhost/127.0.0.1 (channelId=-1) disconnected

docker-compose
 zookeeper:
    container_name: zookeeper
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    networks:
      - microservices-net

  kafka-1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    container_name: kafka-1
    ports:
      - '19092:19092'
      - '9092:9092'
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: LISTENER_INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,LISTENER_EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: LISTENER_INTERNAL://kafka-1:19092,LISTENER_EXTERNAL://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: LISTENER_INTERNAL://kafka-1:19092,LISTENER_EXTERNAL://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: LISTENER_INTERNAL
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 2
      KAFKA_LOG4J_LOGGERS: "kafka.server=DEBUG,kafka.network=TRACE"
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    networks:
      - microservices-net

  kafka-2:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    container_name: kafka-2
    ports:
      - '29092:29092'
      - '9093:9093'
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 2
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: LISTENER_INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,LISTENER_EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: LISTENER_INTERNAL://kafka-2:29092,LISTENER_EXTERNAL://localhost:9093
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: LISTENER_INTERNAL://kafka-2:29092,LISTENER_EXTERNAL://localhost:9093
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: LISTENER_INTERNAL
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 2
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    networks:
      - microservices-net

Spring Kafka configuration (application.yml):
spring:
  kafka:
    producer:
      bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092, localhost:9093
      key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      value-serializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
      properties:
        acks: all

Kafka-2 container logs
INFO [ControllerEventThread controllerId=2] Starting (kafka.controller.ControllerEventManager$ControllerEventThread)
INFO [GroupCoordinator 2]: Starting up. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
INFO [TransactionCoordinator id=2] Starting up. (kafka.coordinator.transaction.TransactionCoordinator)
INFO [TxnMarkerSenderThread-2]: Starting (kafka.coordinator.transaction.TransactionMarkerChannelManager)
DEBUG [Controller id=2] Broker 1 was elected as controller instead of broker 2 (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
ERROR org.apache.kafka.common.errors.ControllerMovedException: Controller moved to another broker. Aborting controller startup procedure
INFO [SocketServer listenerType=ZK_BROKER, nodeId=2] Enabling request processing. (kafka.network.SocketServer)
INFO Awaiting socket connections on kafka-2:29092. (kafka.network.DataPlaneAcceptor)
INFO Awaiting socket connections on localhost:9093. (kafka.network.DataPlaneAcceptor)
INFO Kafka version: 7.7.0-ccs (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
INFO [KafkaServer id=2] started (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
INFO [zk-broker-2-to-controller-alter-partition-channel-manager]: Recorded new ZK controller, from now on will use node kafka-1:19092 (id: 1 rack: null) (kafka.server.NodeToControllerRequestThread)


I checked the connection using Test-NetConnection and confirmed that both Kafka ports (9092 and 9093) are accessible. I expected the Spring application to establish a stable connection to Kafka, but the connection is made briefly and then immediately disconnected, as shown in the logs.

what does the kafka start-up log show?

Added logs to the  question

where is you spring container running, inside or outside docker?

Spring app running outside

Looks fine to me, you just need localhost:9092 in the spring properties, here is an example of mine.

It dosn't work for me if you meaned to write only one broker 9092 in properties , i face the same mistake. I tried to use  only one broker with the same properties before and it worked, but not with the cluster. This is my first expirience with more than 1 broker

This question is similar to: Connect to Kafka running in Docker. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I resolved the issue by changing the host in the KAFKA_LISTENERS configuration from localhost to 0.0.0.0. Everything started working correctly afterward.
  kafka-1:
    environment:
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: LISTENER_INTERNAL://kafka-1:19092,LISTENER_EXTERNAL://0.0.0.0:9092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: LISTENER_INTERNAL://kafka-1:19092,LISTENER_EXTERNAL://localhost:9092

  kafka-2:
    environment:
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: LISTENER_INTERNAL://kafka-2:29092,LISTENER_EXTERNAL://0.0.0.0:9093
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: LISTENER_INTERNAL://kafka-2:29092,LISTENER_EXTERNAL://localhost:9093

This configuration allowed clients to connect properly.
